# Check all rows if meets criteria for a set of records

Tags: sql, select, grouping

I'm trying to create a query to check if all lines of a Sales Order have these 5 columns equal to zero then execute stored procedure. If any of the lines do not all meet the same criteria do not execute. I need to grab all lines where Sales Order equals then check my columns qtytoinv, qtyfulfil, atyalloc, qtyremai, qtyslctd if all columns for all lines = 0 execute.

Results of current table:

```
SOPNUMBE        ATY         QTYRE   QTYINV  QTYFUL  QTYSLCTD
DS-19020        0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
DS-19020        0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
DS-19020        0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
DS-19020        0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
DS-19020        0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
DS-19020        0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
```

Since not all lines do not equal zero skip over this set or do not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the table by `sponumbe` and filter out rows with other values:

```
SELECT sponumbe
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY sponumber
HAVING   MAX(aty)      = 0 AND
         MAX(qtyre)    = 0 AND
         MAX(qtyinv)   = 0 AND
         MAX(qtyful)   = 0 AND
         MAX(qtyslctd) = 0
```

Comment: THANK YOU Mureinik!  I had been sitting there for an hour trying to figure this out.  I  ran that quick query and it filtered the results as expected. Now just to factor it in to my stored procedure.  YOU ROCK!